# Undefined variable: name_tags (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\portofolio\resources\views\content.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting `below` error :

> Undefined variable: name_tags (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portofolio\resources\views\content.blade.php)

**Code :**

```
<?php $currentLoopData = $artikel->tags;
$env->addLoop($currentLoopData); 
foreach($currentLoopData as $d):
    $env->incrementLoopIndices();
    $loop = $env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <small><?php echo e($d -> $name_tags); ?></small>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
    $env->popLoop(); 
    $loop = $env->getLastLoop();
?>
```

**My database :**

[image]

Comment: Where is `$name_tags = ` written?

Comment: Looks like you want **$d->name_tags** instead of **$d->$name_tags** (note the extra $ in the second version)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$d->name_tags` instead of `$d -> $name_tags`.

Your code should look like this;

```
<?php $currentLoopData = $artikel->tags;
$env->addLoop($currentLoopData); 
foreach($currentLoopData as $d):
    $env->incrementLoopIndices();
    $loop = $env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <small><?php echo e($d->name_tags); ?></small>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
    $env->popLoop(); 
    $loop = $env->getLastLoop();
?>
```